# ExtJs Json missing ) in parenthetical Zend Framework

Tags: php, json, extjs, zend-framework

I've got this ghost error where, as the title suggests, it shows missing ) in parenthetical. I've already read some questions similar and every answer suggests that there's something wrong with JSON. I can't found it in my code though. Here it is :

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/procurement/procurementpurchaseorder/cekcost',
    method: 'POST',
    params: params,
    success: function (result, request) {
        var returnData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(result.responseText);
        if (returnData.success) {
            myPanel = Ext.getCmp('abs-budget-panel');
            myPanel.body.load({
                url: '/procurement/procurement/apppo',
                scripts: true,
                params: params
            });
         }
     },
     failure: function(action){
          if(action.failureType == 'server'){
              obj = Ext.util.JSON.decode(action.responseText);
              Ext.Msg.alert('Error!', obj.errors.reason);
          }else{
              Ext.Msg.alert('Warning!', 'Server is unreachable : ' + action.responseText);
          }
     }
});
```

And the return POST JSON from the first url :

```
etc [{"prj_kode": "Q000169", "prj_nama": "Telkomsel IBC 2014", "sit_kode": "210", 
"sit_nama": "Poin Square", "sup_kode": "VDR0007", "sup_nama": "Andrew Hongkong Ltd", 
"tgldeliesti": "2017-05-29", "tujuan": "Jl. Danau Singkarak No. 65 B-C, Sei Agul, Medan 20117", 
"payterm": "-", "typepo": "undefined", "invoiceto": "PT QDC Technologies", 
"budgettype": "Project", "ket": "-", "ketin": "-", "val_kode": "IDR", "rateidr": "0", "top": "0"}] 

file[] 

posts[{"urut": "24", "workid": "1026", "workname": "Material for Common RF Work", 
"pr_number": "PRF-15000984", "prj_kode": "Q000145", "sit_kode": "210", "prj_nama": "Telkomsel IBC 2014", 
"sit_nama": "Poin Square", "kode_brg": "410011-LEON", "nama_brg": "Coaxial Cable - 7/8 inch", 
"qty": "1", uom": "Mtr", "val_kode": "IDR", "currency": "0", "price": "62475",   
"tgl_pr": "2017-04-10", "totalPR": "3399.0000", "pricePR": "62475.0000", "totalPricePR": 212352525, 
"totalPO": 3001, "totalPricePO": "129900000.00000000", "totalPrice": 62475, 
"id": "78173", "sup_kode": "VDR0007", "sup_nama": "Andrew Hongkong Ltd",
"invoiceto": "PT QDC Technologies", "ket":"", "tujuan":"Jl. Danau Singkarak No. 65 B-C, Sei Agul, Medan 20117", 
"tgl_kirim": "2017-05-29T00:00:00", "po_term": "-", "top": "0", "budgettype": "Project", 
"net_act": 208", "qtySupp": "1", "priceSupp": "62475", "totalPriceSupp": 62475,  
"statusppn": "N", "valueppn": 0, "valueppnSupp": 0, "percentppn": 0, "gtotal": 62475}]
```

I think my JSON structure is spot on. So, what am I missing? Please tell if you need more information regarding the question. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your etc json is correct.Problem is with your last json named **posts**. Below is updated json.Some of attributes in json were not formatted correctly by double quotes.Check [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/) by comparing your both jsons.Format your json from [here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/?utm_content=buffer2b790&utm_medium=social&utm_source=app.net&utm_campaign=buffer).

> {"urut":"24","workid":"1026","workname":"Material for Common RF Work","pr_number":"PRF-15000984","prj_kode":"Q000145","sit_kode":"210","prj_nama":"Telkomsel IBC 2014","sit_nama":"Poin Square","kode_brg":"410011-LEON","nama_brg":"Coaxial Cable - 7/8 inch","qty":"1","uom":"Mtr","val_kode":"IDR","currency":"0","price":"62475","tgl_pr":"2017-04-10","totalPR":"3399.0000","pricePR":"62475.0000","totalPricePR":212352525,"totalPO":3001,"totalPricePO":"129900000.00000000","totalPrice":62475,"id":"78173","sup_kode":"VDR0007","sup_nama":"AndrewHongkongLtd","invoiceto":"PTQDCTechnologies","ket":"","tujuan":"Jl.DanauSingkarakNo.65B-C,   SeiAgul,   Medan20117","tgl_kirim":"2017-05-29T00: 00: 00","po_term":"-","top":"0","budgettype":"Project","net_act":"208","qtySupp":"1","priceSupp":"62475","totalPriceSupp":62475,"statusppn":"N","valueppn":0,"valueppnSupp":0,"percentppn":0,"gtotal":62475}

Comment: I already change the JSON code above, and it's recognized as JSON, but the error still persist.

Comment: I copied above json only and this was culprit which failed.Did you check by comparing both jsons ?